# What is the definition for the noun "challenge" in the phrase "mount challenge"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrases, nouns

This context comes from the book "Black Rednecks And White Liberals"
by Thomas Sowell.

**Basically answer the question at the end of the post and I will be satisfied unless the answer is "no" :)**

"Yet attempts to abolish slavery in the non-Western world provoked armed uprisings within the Ottoman Empire, and elsewhere peoples unable to directly **mount challenges** on the battlefield nevertheless engaged in massive evasions and concealments of their continued trade in human beings."

**The same example** is in the Cambridge Dictionary definition of the word "mount":

to organize and begin an activity or event:
**to mount** an attack/campaign/**challenge**/protest

Is this the meaning of the word "challenge" in this phrase, in these definitions below?

**"challenge" noun:**

1)a stimulating task or problem

*looking for new challenges*(Merriam-Webster)

**"challenge" noun:**

2)A test of one's abilities or resources in a demanding but stimulating undertaking:

*a career that offers a challenge.*(American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language)*emphasized text*

Is the sense of the phrase "to mount a challenge" that the person doing it must **organize a demanding undertaking for their opponent which they will face?**

Comment: See [this usage chart,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unable+to+mount+a+challenge%2Cunable+to+mount+challenges&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) showing just how uncommon plural ***to mount challenges*** is compared to singular ***to mount a challenge***.

Answer (score 1):

Oxford Languages gives this as the main definition:

> A call to someone to participate in a competitive situation or *fight to decide who is superior in terms of ability or strength*. (my italics)

The Eastern slave traders were not able to fight battles against their opponents, but found other ways to resist them.

The phrase would be *mount* **a** *challenge.*

Answer (score 0):

Wiktionary has "Confrontation" and particularly "A bid to overcome something".

Cambridge is a little less clear in this case.  The closest sense seems to be "an invitation for someone to compete against you".  If you mount a challenge on the battlefield, you invite your opponent to fight you.